# Adding a new HDD to an HP DL380 G8 server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

I'm trying to add a new HDD to an HP DL380 server running Ubuntu 12.04. I can see the drive in iLo and in ACU, but when I open gparted in Linux, I don't see the new drive.

I do see an error message from gparted though:
input/output error during read on /dev/sdb

I see some messages in dmesg related to sdb:

```
[278733.568189] hpsa 0000:02:00.0: cp ffff880036900000 has check condition: unknown type: Sense: 0x3, ASC: 0x11, ASCQ: 0x0, Returning result: 0x2, cmd=[28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00] 
[278733.568227] sd 2:0:0:2: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[278733.568229] sd 2:0:0:2: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=invalid driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[278733.568231] sd 2:0:0:2: [sdb]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
[278733.568233] sd 2:0:0:2: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[278733.568236] sd 2:0:0:2: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[278733.568241] end_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
```

I'm not really sure how to fix this. I don't know if it's an Ubuntu/Linux issue or an HP one.

Edit:

my Smart Array configuration is:

```
$ hpacucli ctrl all show config detail

Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)
   Bus Interface: PCI
   Slot: 0
   Serial Number: 5001438021098CD0
   Cache Serial Number: PBKUC0ARH2B1E0
   RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Disabled
   Controller Status: OK
   Hardware Revision: B
   Firmware Version: 3.04
   Rebuild Priority: Medium
   Expand Priority: Medium
   Surface Scan Delay: 15 secs
   Surface Scan Mode: Idle
   Queue Depth: Automatic
   Monitor and Performance Delay: 60  min
   Elevator Sort: Enabled
   Degraded Performance Optimization: Disabled
   Inconsistency Repair Policy: Disabled
   Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
   Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
   Post Prompt Timeout: 0 secs
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: OK
   Cache Ratio: 10% Read / 90% Write
   Drive Write Cache: Disabled
   Total Cache Size: 1024 MB
   Total Cache Memory Available: 816 MB
   No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
   Cache Backup Power Source: Capacitors
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
   SATA NCQ Supported: True
   Spare Activation Mode: Activate on drive failure
   Controller Temperature (C): 60
   Cache Module Temperature (C): 29
   Capacitor Temperature  (C): 22

   Array: A
      Interface Type: SAS
      Unused Space: 0  MB
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data



      Logical Drive: 1
         Size: 136.7 GB
         Fault Tolerance: 1
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 35132
         Strip Size: 256 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 256 KB
         Status: OK
         Caching:  Enabled
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001C4BC300EE849726EFEB06
         Disk Name: /dev/sda
         Mount Points: /boot 244 MB
         OS Status: LOCKED
         Logical Drive Label: AF49B97A50014380225A7250A91C
         Mirror Group 0:
            physicaldrive 1I:2:1 (port 1I:box 2:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
         Mirror Group 1:
            physicaldrive 1I:2:2 (port 1I:box 2:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
         Drive Type: Data

      physicaldrive 1I:2:1
         Port: 1I
         Box: 2
         Bay: 1
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 146 GB
         Rotational Speed: 15000
         Firmware Revision: HPD1
         Serial Number: 6XM0J34W0000M241M5WX
         Model: HP      EH0146FBQDC
         Current Temperature (C): 28
         Maximum Temperature (C): 52
         PHY Count: 2
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps, Unknown
         Drive Authentication Status: OK
         Carrier Application Version: 11
         Carrier Bootloader Version: 6

      physicaldrive 1I:2:2
         Port: 1I
         Box: 2
         Bay: 2
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 146 GB
         Rotational Speed: 15000
         Firmware Revision: HPDH
         Serial Number: 6TB3AL7G0000B239CT5T
         Model: HP      EH0146FAWJB
         Current Temperature (C): 27
         Maximum Temperature (C): 56
         PHY Count: 2
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps, Unknown
         Drive Authentication Status: OK
         Carrier Application Version: 11
         Carrier Bootloader Version: 6


   Array: B
      Interface Type: SATA
      Unused Space: 0  MB
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data



      Logical Drive: 2
         Size: 931.5 GB
         Fault Tolerance: 0
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 65535
         Strip Size: 256 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 256 KB
         Status: OK
         Caching:  Enabled
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001C2251BCA727E4E42CBE5A
         Disk Name: /dev/sdb
         Mount Points: None
         Logical Drive Label: ACE9761A5001438021098CD0589F
         Drive Type: Data

      physicaldrive 1I:2:3
         Port: 1I
         Box: 2
         Bay: 3
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 1 TB
         Rotational Speed: 5400
         Firmware Revision: 01.01A01
         Serial Number:      WD-WXC1A57816H1
         Model: ATA     WDC WD10JPVX-11J
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 23
         Maximum Temperature (C): 29
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         Drive Authentication Status: OK
         Carrier Application Version: 11
         Carrier Bootloader Version: 6


   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model SRCv8x6G) 380
      Device Number: 380
      Firmware Version: RevB
      WWID: 5001438021098CDF
      Vendor ID: PMCSIERA
      Model: SRCv8x6G
```

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is EoL (End of Life). Please upgrade to a supported LTS release.

Comment: I don't know if it'd fix your issue, but have you tried [updating the Smart Array P420i firmware](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5295169&swItemId=MTX_4aec44ac24e64df39c9ed95782&swEnvOid=4184#tab-history)?  It's version 3.04 (2012-09-04), but the latest is version 8.32 (2017-11-02).  There have been several major fixes since your installed version.